# Static Pages and Embed Tag

Tags: pages

I have come across this issue and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have this code in an include file:

```
<!-- .site-title -->
          <hgroup>
          {exp:channel:entries channel="site_image" limit="1"}
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="{site_url}" title="title here" rel="home"><img src="{site_image}" alt="{title}"></a></h1>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
            {if segment_1 == ""}{site_intro}{/if}
          </hgroup>
          <!-- .site-title -->
```

This all seems fine and works on all the pages of the site it is embedded into, except static pages created with the 'Pages Module'. On those pages I get this output from the browser:

```
<!-- .site-title -->
          <hgroup>


          </hgroup>
          <!-- .site-title -->
```

Nothing at all appears between the  tag pair. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first thing to check would be to make sure the URL you are accessing matches the Pages URI that you set in the pages control panel. To make absolutely super-duper sure, add `url_title="{segment_1}"` and `dynamic="no"` to your `{exp:channel:entries}` tag.

Comment: May thanks for your input, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a classic dynamic="no" situation. Add this to your exp:channel:entries tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="site_image" limit="1" dynamic="no"}
```

Comment: Many thanks to all. Yes this worked fine. Would you be able to explain why that worked?

Comment: dynamic="no" basically lets the exp:channel:entries tag ignore any information that might be present in the url. It's a classic EE quirk that trips up even experienced devs. Full documentation here: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic